# Yii2 ActiveRecord Stat relations

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How to create stat relations in version 2 of Yii?

Do you create a dynamic relation query by changing the "select" of the returned ActiveQuery? 
If so, is this good when it comes to performance?

Am I better off executing my own sql query or using query builder?

Comment: See docs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data

Comment: I did, can't find anything mentioning stat relations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply use the same `ActiveQuery`, e.g. :

```
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getOrdersCount()
{
    return $this->getOrders()->count();
}
```